# GroupBy with Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, group-by, linq-to-objects

I am strugling with a GroupBy for Linq. I guess I can't do it in one expression but have no clue how to solve the problem.

I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class Shipment {
  public string PortOfOrigin{get;set;}
  public string PortOfDestination{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices{get;set;}
}

public class Invoice{
  public string InvoicePeriod {get;set;}
  public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

I have a collection of Shipments that all have a collection of Invoice. Here is an example.

```
List<Shipment> shipments = new List<Shipment>
{
    new Shipment { PortOfOrigin = "USLOS", PortOfDestionation = "UKLON", 
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 1000},
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 2000},
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201107", Amount = 1000}
        }
    },
    new Shipment { PortOfOrigin = "USLOS", PortOfDestionation = "UKLON", 
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 3000},
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201107", Amount = 2000}
        }
    },
    new Shipment { PortOfOrigin = "USDAL", PortOfDestionation = "UKLON", 
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 3000}
        }
    }
};
```

Now I want to group by the following:

Shipment.PortOfOrigin, Shipment.PortOfDestionation, Shipment.Invoices.InvoicePeriod.

So I want the result like this

```
PortOfOrigin    PortOfDestination   InvoicePeriod   Amount
------------------------------------------------------------------------
USLOS           UKLON               201106          6000
USLOS           UKLON               201107          3000
USDAL           UKLON               201106          3000
```

Is this even possible to do a group like this where I want to group on the Invoices.InvoicePeriod?

Comment: +1 for the example data and the example of the results you want.  It's rare to get a question which is so clear and well defined :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  I've updated my answer to include the number of Shipments.  This requires the shipment to have an ID field.

---

The following will do the trick:

```
//first flatten the data so it's easier to manipulate
var query = from s in shipments
            from i in s.Invoices
            select new
            {
                s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier,
                s.PortOfOrigin,
                s.PortOfDestination,
                i.InvoicePeriod,
                i.Amount
            };

//group the data as desired
var grouping = query.GroupBy(q => new { q.PortOfOrigin, q.PortOfDestination, q.InvoicePeriod });

//finally sum the amounts
var results = from g in grouping
              select new
              {
                  g.Key.PortOfOrigin,
                  g.Key.PortOfDestination,
                  g.Key.InvoicePeriod,
                  Amount = g.Select(s => s.Amount).Sum(),
                  NumberOfShipments = g.Select(s => s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier).Distinct().Count()
              };
```

Here's the output:

[image]

**UPDATE:** As promised, here's a complete working example:

```
public class Shipment {
  public Guid ShipmentUniqueIdentifier{get;set;}
  public string PortOfOrigin{get;set;}
  public string PortOfDestination{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices{get;set;}
}

public class Invoice {
  public string InvoicePeriod {get;set;}
  public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}

List<Shipment> shipments = new List<Shipment>
{
    new Shipment { PortOfOrigin = "USLOS", PortOfDestination = "UKLON", ShipmentUniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 1000},
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 2000},
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201107", Amount = 1000}
        }
    },
    new Shipment { PortOfOrigin = "USLOS", PortOfDestination = "UKLON", ShipmentUniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 3000},
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201107", Amount = 2000}
        }
    },
    new Shipment { PortOfOrigin = "USDAL", PortOfDestination = "UKLON", ShipmentUniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid(), 
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice{InvoicePeriod = "201106", Amount = 3000}
        }
    }
};

void Main()
{
    //first flatten the data so it's easier to manipulate
    var query = from s in shipments
                from i in s.Invoices
                select new
                {
                    s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier,
                    s.PortOfOrigin,
                    s.PortOfDestination,
                    i.InvoicePeriod,
                    i.Amount
                };

    //group the data as desired
    var grouping = query.GroupBy(q => new { q.PortOfOrigin, q.PortOfDestination, q.InvoicePeriod });

    //finally sum the amounts
    var results = from g in grouping
                  select new
                  {
                      g.Key.PortOfOrigin,
                      g.Key.PortOfDestination,
                      g.Key.InvoicePeriod,
                      Amount = g.Select(s => s.Amount).Sum(),
                      NumberOfShipments = g.Select(s => s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier).Distinct().Count()
                  };

    //output the results
    results.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I thought about flatterned the data, but I was thinking that I needed to create a new class to do that, but I don't have to do that if I use your first linq statement.

Comment: Is there a way to get the right number of shipments also included here. If I only add the g.Count() to it then I will get the same numbers as I have invoices for each group (since it's flattende out). So how could I only get the numbers of shipments for this example above it should be: 2,2 and 1. And not 3,2 and 1

Comment: @Magnus I've updated my answer to give the number of shipments (an upvote would be a nice reward ;-))

Comment: Thanks! Yes a reward is the least I can give you :)

Comment: I tried it out in my world and it didn't work... I addedd this line:  SummarizedShipments = g.Distinct(s => s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier).Count() and got the exception: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<AnonymousType#1>' because it is not a delegate type. !?!?!?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what the problem could be, I've updated my answer and attached my complete code listing so you can see a working example.  If you still can't get it working, paste me a complete example in your question and I'll take a look at what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Docta! I took your code and put it into Linq Pad and runned it as a C# program and I got the same exception as I have got before. My guess is that we must have some difference in our .NET versions or something. Anyway I thanks for the help and I will dig into this query and see if I can solve it in some way.

Comment: Aha, you must be using .Net 3.5.  It seems that the signature of Distinct has changed in .Net 4.  You need to change `g.Distinct(s => s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier).Count()` to `g.Select(s => s.ShipmentUniqueIdentifier).Distinct().Count()`  I've updated my answer with this.